# What is an efficient way to joining two tables of data stored in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two dictionary's of numpy arrays representing tables of data. 
The first table is a list of jobs (job_no) and their start dates (start_date).
The second table is a list of tasks (task_no) to be completed for each job.
I want to effectively add the start dates to the task-level table by joining on the job_no.

Below is an example of what the tables look like with the proper start dates added to the task-level table.

```
job_no | start_date    job_no | task_no .    start_date
_______ ___________    _______ ________ .    __________
0      | 2019-01-01    0      | 1       .    2019-01-01
1      | 2019-01-04    0      | 2       . +  2019-01-01
2      | 2019-01-20    0      | 3       .    2019-01-01
3      | 2019-02-03    1      | 1       .    2019-01-04
4      | 2019-02-13    1      | 2       .    2019-01-04
...
```

I typically try to avoid using python loops and instead use numpy functions for efficiency, but am stuck on how to do that for this situation.

My dataset has about 25000 jobs and 100000 tasks, the code below is very slow in accomplishing the above.

```
jobs = {job_no : np.array(...), start_date : np.array(...)}
tasks = {job_no : np.array(...), task_no : np.array(...)}

tasks['start_date'] = np.empty(len(tasks['job_no']))

for job_ind, job_no in enumerate(jobs['job_no']):
    inds = np.where(tasks['job_no'] == job_no)
    tasks['start_date'][inds] = jobs['start_date'][job_ind]
```

Is there a much more efficient way to do this using numpy functions?

Comment: Not sure if it applies, the information in this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983268/4545530 may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pandas to define a dataframe and then do a simple outer join. Depends on from where you are reading the contents but try to get it to a pandas dataframe. Lets say you manage to do that as PD1 for the job no and start date, PD2 as task no and start date. Then the simple join function on job_no :

```
PD3= pandas.merge(PD1, PD2, how='outer', on=['job_no'])
```